# Как скрыть текст внутри блока?

Tags: css

Есть блок с текстом. Как скрыть текст внутри этого блока?

```html
<div class="el">Текст</div>
```

Comment: а скрыть сами пункты, или обернуть контент в `span` и скрыть нельзя?

Comment: @teran, это не интересно. Вдруг у меня куча текста с прерываниями (между текстом стоят другие элементы: картинки, блоки) и мне что, каждый кусок текста нужно в span оборачивать?

Comment: `font-size: 0;` можно так :)

Comment: @L.Vadim, так добавьте этот вариант ответом. Я задал вопрос, что бы вообще все варианты узнать )

Comment: @L.Vadim я тоже подумывал это написать, но тут на самом деле куча побочки, например с em

Comment: ну исползьуйте `div`, а не `span` принципиальной разницы нет. Или я не понимаю, в чем проблема?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму под цвет эт фока это будет visibility:hidden, но не display:none, а вообще тут тогда и color:transparent подойдёт :)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, ну если я говорю `display: none`, то мне кажется это понятно, что должно съезжать всё. Если бы я хотел просто скрыть, я бы написал `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @Yuri, ок. Простого универсального цсс хака мне неизвестно и в его существовании я сомневаюсь, вышеупомянутый font-size 0 приближается к этому ближе всего.

Comment: @andreymal побочки правда много, ну это как вариант

Comment: @Yuri Добавьте в вопрос более сложный код, чтобы было легче понять задачу. Нынешний пример провоцирует поставить минус, а `(между текстом стоят другие элементы: картинки, блоки)` - уже интереснее.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, во-первых, у меня задача просто скрыть весь текст в блоке. Во-вторых, если хотите ставьте минус

Comment: @Yuri Я хочу, чтобы хороший вопрос стал понятнее. Сейчас, чтобы увидеть суть проблемы, надо прочитать комментарии. Иначе неясно, что мешает скрыть весь блок вместе с текстом.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, может то, что сам блок должно быть видно? Не?

Comment: Мне кажется, я обычно заворачиваю каждый фрагмент текста в отдельный блок, в котором он не смешивается с посторонними элементами. Поэтому. наверное, мне трудно понять задачу...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов реализации скрытия текста:

1. Просто обернуть текст в блоке в span и скрыть его

   ```css
   .el > span {display: none;}
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="el"><span>Текст</span></div>
   ```
2. Установить элементу `font-size: 0`. Но это способ работает не во всех старых браузерах

   ```css
   .el {font-size: 0}
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="el">Текст</div>
   ```
3. Установить `text-indent: -9999px (или -999em);` или `text-indent: -999em;`

   ```css
   .el {
     text-indent: -9999px; /*или -999em*/
     white-space: nowrap; 
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="el">Текст</div>
   ```
4. Вариант с использованием того же  `text-indent`, но только с определённым сочетанием стилей: `text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`

   ```css
   .el {
     text-indent: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="el">Текст</div>
   ```
5. Вариант приближённый к скрытию. Во всяком случае текста не видно

   ```css
   .el {
     font-size: 1px;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="el">Текст</div>
   ```
6. Использовать нулевой шрифт. Т.е. специальный шрифт, в котором нет букв. К сожалению, я такого найти не смог

Answer (score 4):

Использовал `font-size:0;` таким образом скрыл текст

```css
.list {
}
.list-item {
  /* text-display: none; */
  font-size:0;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background:green;
}
div {display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red;}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Пункт 0</li>
  <li class="list-item">Пункт 1<div></div>Продолжение</li>
  <li class="list-item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="list-item">Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хм, в Firefox он внезапно не скрылся, слева от зелёного прямоугольника появились пиксели являющиеся текстом, по одному на строку

Comment: Походу эти пиксели — кружочки от `<li>`

Comment: да это кружочки `li`

Comment: на всякий случай: list-style: none; если надо скрыть кружочки (а надо ли? они тоже не текст =))

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму вроде в вопросе про кружочки не скзано

Comment: еще можно белый цвет поставить, текст будет не виден, но если выделить, то увидишь. Что-то тип загадки, где надо найти текст.

Answer (score 2):

если важно, чтоб текст был но его не было видно - можно использовать:

```
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Можно ещё указать `color: transparent`

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-item {
   visibility: none;
}
```

Comment: Ну этот же вариант скроет всё, а не только текст

Comment: Нет такого значения. Поменяй `none` на `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно скрыть только часть текста (например чтобы при наведении показывать весь блок):

```css
.block {
width:45px;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden
}

.block:hover {
width:110px;
transition:0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Видно Невидно</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

css

```
.list-item {
  content: none;
}
```

Comment: Роман, у вас уже ест ответ, [дополните его, а не создавайте новый](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2350/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81). И -- оформляйте код как код, вы же уже делали это в других ответах.

Comment: @AK, во-первых, это разные ответы и не надо ничего дополнять. Во-вторых, я знаю только один браузер, гда описанное в этом ответе работает: Опера 12. По стандарту это должно игнорироваться.